# How do I to capture the cell reference to paste in another sheet.

Tags: reference, cell

For example, lets say I have 2 sheet: Sheet-1 and Sheet-2. I want to have a cell in Sheet-2 reference a cell in Sheet-1, but I want to do it with a quick copy motion on the cell in Sheet-1.

The reason I need this is because as I type in the information in one sheet this data is needed in other sheets as well. I want to quickly copy the cell with its address and paste it in my other sheets.

I'm looking for a quick shortcut, no formulas.

Comment: I'm not sure how you can do this without some formula/VBA scripts.

Comment: Look at the Kutools reference in the following link https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3767-excel-auto-copy-cell.html it might be helpful.